# url-pattern in security-contraints casing issue

Tags: tomcat

I can lock down a specific resource using security-constraints in tomcat.  But it only locks down the path using the exact casing specified.  I can still access the resource ( file) simply by changing case.

What is the best way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat enforces case sensitive access to resources (even on case insensitive file systems like Windows) by default so changing the case should never allow you to bypass security constraints. I can think of a couple of ways this might happen:

1. You ignored the secuirty warning in the docs and set allowLinking to true on a case insensitive file system.
2. You are using a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat and have configured in such a way as to bypass the security constraints (if you have configured a reverse proxy we'd need to know which one and how it was configured to help further).